# How to find a "/*" character in a string

Tags: java

I'm trying to find specific string matches using either .contains or .indexOf, but when I search for "*/" or "/*" in a string, I'm unable to find that combination.

For example:

```
String exampleString = "/* SQL Comment */";
String commentStart = "/*";
String commentEnd = "*/";

if(exampleString.contains(commentStart) || exampleString.contains(commentEnd){
   System.out.println("Comment: " + exampleString);
}
```

When I run the program, I do not get the comment returned. When I try to escape the star character or slash character, still no luck.

For example:

```
String exampleString = "/* SQL Comment */";

if(exampleString.contains("\\*\\/"){
    System.out.println("Comment: " + exampleString);
}
```

How would you find the slash star combination? I'd also like to add that this is not for preventing SQL injection attacks. This is just for searching for SQL comments.

Comment: Assuming that you really have 2 `)` characters before the beginning of the `if` block, your code does print the line.  There is no need to escape the substring you're looking for, because `contains` doesn't treat its argument as a regular expression.

Comment: Your first example should work

Comment: Does it work with a CharSequence, as said in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html?

Comment: As other comments noted, your first example is fine except for a missing parenthesis. How is the result you're getting different from what you were expecting?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just tested it and it does work, but what is weird is that for the string I am looking through, it still isn't being found. At least it isn't an issue with the way I am looking for the characters. Must be something else in my code.

Comment: Then give us your string and maybe we can help you.

Comment: The string works if I declare it a string (it's just a normal SQL comment like the example above), but the process in which I am splitting and parsing through a lot of SQL code must have a logical issue. Sorry for wasting everyone's time. It's an issue somewhere else in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to extract the comment? If so you need to use a Pattern and a Matcher. Here's a sample implementation:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String exampleString = "/* SQL Comment */ Some text /* Another SQL comment */  /* A comment without end!";
        Pattern start = Pattern.compile("/\\*");
        Pattern end = Pattern.compile("\\*/");
        Matcher startMatcher = start.matcher(exampleString);
        Matcher endMatcher = end.matcher(exampleString);

        while(startMatcher.find()) {
            int startIndex = startMatcher.end();
            int endIndex = exampleString.length();
            System.out.println("Start index: " + startIndex);
            if(endMatcher.find()) {
                endIndex = endMatcher.start();
                System.out.println("End index: " + endIndex);

            } else {
                System.out.println("Comment does not end");
            }
            System.out.println("String: '" + exampleString.substring(startIndex, endIndex) + "'");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Start index: 2
End index: 15
String: ' SQL Comment '
Start index: 30
End index: 51
String: ' Another SQL comment '
Start index: 56
Comment does not end
String: ' A comment without end!'
```

Comment: No, that isn't what I'm trying to do. Just trying to find it in general at this point, but eventually I will need to do what you've written. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. It was an issue somewhere else in the code where the string wasn't making it to my code trying to find it. Sorry to waste your time.

Comment: No problem, I like writing code for Stackoverflow :).